# An exercise on Baire Category Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, baire-category

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a complete metric space. Let $\Phi$ be a non-empty set of continuous real valued functions on $X$. Define $g : X \to \mathbb R \cup \infty$ by $g(x)=\sup\{f(x):f\in\Phi\}$. Suppose that $g(x)<\infty$ for each $x \in X$. Let $G$ be the set of all $x$ such that there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $g$ is bounded above on $V$. Prove that $G$ is open and dense in $X$.

Comment: I don't even know what to start. The hint says Baire Category Theorem may help.

Comment: Maybe you can use that if 
$$
G_n := \{x\in X \ | \ \exists \epsilon>0 : |g(y)| < n \  ( \ \forall y \in B(x,\epsilon) \ )\}
$$

then $G = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}G_n$. I'm not entirely sure this will work though. I'll update you as soon as I figure it out.

Comment: @qualcuno I am unable to appreciate the significance of this result. I am guessing that $\Phi$ is kind of collection of functions which is "equibounded" (borrowing from the concept of equicontinuity). If I am correct, in that case, what is $G$? Is it the collection of points where $g$ is continuous? Is this result in some way similar to the following fact (which is also provable by BCT)?
 
 Let $f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to a function $ f $. Then $\exists D$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$ so that $f$ is continuous at every point in $D$.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul Hi, I had forgotten about this question entirely--and it has been almost six years! The family $\Phi$ can be any family of functions, for intuition you can even take $\Phi$ to be all continous functions $X \to \Bbb R$. The point is that $g(x) < \infty$ says that there is a bound for $f(x)$ which does not depend on $f$, only on $x$. Moreover, if $g$ is bounded in some neighbourhood $V \ni x$, then $f(y)$ is bounded for the same constant, regardless of who $f$ is, as long as $y \in V$. Thus $\Phi$ is "locally equibounded" at $V$, so to speak.

Comment: I guess roughly speaking the statement says that any family of functions is "locally equibounded almost everywhere", i.e. in a dense subset of $X$, But again, this is just my way to interpret the statement, in a quick second read, six years after I read it the first time :P

Comment: @qualcuno Thanks for your reply. I will have a fair bit of hesitation interpreting dense as "almost everywhere". However, your previous reply does make more sense to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

First the fact that $G$ is open. Take $x\in G$. There exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ and  a real $M$ such that $g(y)\leq M$ for all $y\in V$. There exists an open subset $U$ of $V$ containing $x$. Then every $z\in U$ is in $G$, hence $U\subset G$, and we are done.

We now show that $G$ is dense (this imply $G$ not empty). Let $U$ a not empty subset of $X$. Recall that as an open subset of a Baire space (as a complete metric space is a Baire space), $U$ is also a Baire space. For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, put $F_n=\{x\in U, g(x)\leq n\}$. Then it is clear that $\cup F_n=U$. We show that $F_n$ is closed in $U$. For that let $x_k\in F_n$, $x_k\to x\in U$. We have $g(x_k)\leq n$, hence for $f\in \Phi$, $f(x_k)\leq n$ . As $f$ is continous, this imply that $f(x)\leq n$, and then that $g(x)\leq n$, hence $x\in F_n$. By Baire's theorem, there exist an $m$ such that the interior $W$ of $F_m$ is not empty. Clearly, $W\subset G$. Hence $U\cap G$ is not empty and this  show that $G$ is dense.